# Como borrar las keys cuyo valor no coincidan en al menos un valor de otra key, en un diccionario anidado

Tags: python, condiciones, diccionarios

tras revisar por todo internet, tristemente estoy preguntando de nuevo, y digo tristemente porque siento que estoy preguntando más que aprendiendo, pero bueno, el tema es que, tengo un diccionario de títulos y géneros, y quiero borrar aquellos géneros y sus respectivos títulos que no coincidan en al menos un género, con otros 2 géneros que consigo con un input

esto es todo lo que he intentado:

```
diccionario = {
    "Peliculas": [
        {
            "Titulo": "A",
            "Generos": ["Drama", "Belico"]
        },
        {
            "Titulo": "B",
            "Generos": ["Accion", "Belico"]
        }
    ]
}

generos = input("Elige 2 géneros ")

    for item in diccionario["Peliculas"]:
        if item["Generos"] in generos:
           del item["Generos"]
           del item["Titulo"]
```

el problema es que esto elimina también aquellos que no coinciden en todos los géneros, pero si en al menos 1.

También estuve investigando sobre la función any() pero no logré usarla con un diccionario anidado

Comment: Eeee.... el diccionario que muestras no tiene géneros ._.

Comment: @Christian perdon ahi lo arregle toy re tonto je xd

Comment: haz probado con hacer `if all([generos[i] in peli["Generos"] for i in range(len(generos))])`??

Comment: si yo elijo el género belico, cual diccionario se tendría que eliminar?

Comment: @Christian no he probado con eso porque tengo entendido que con all() se toma en cuenta todos los géneros, o sea, si coincide en al menos 1 también lo borrara no?, de todas formas, acabo de probarlo con un print al final y al parecer no se cumplió la condición

Comment: `all()` verifica si todos los elementos son True

Comment: @Christian si eliges Belico no se tendría que borrar ninguno, la idea es que se borre aquel que no tiene ningún género de los que elegiste, probe con in pero también borra aquellos que tienen 1 género solo de los 2 que especificaste

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128637/discussion-between-christian-and-kalio).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recordemos que `any()` verifica su algún valor de una estructura de datos (en este caso listas) es `True`, por lo que si negamos la expresión obtendremos lo que queremos, pero ¿Cómo usamos `any()`?. La función `any()` trabaja bajo objetos iterables por lo que tendremos que crear uno, la forma que encontré de hacerlo es creando una lista de valores booleanos, esto con una simple comprensión de lista para verificar si cada valor de la clave `Genero` se encuentra dentro de los valores ingresados por el usuario, a esa lista resultante le aplicamos la función `any()` que verificará si algún valor es `True` (ósea si algún valor de la clave Genero se encuentra en lo que ingresó el usuario) y negaremos eso, tal que, al momento de armar la condición solo se cumplirá si todos los elementos son `False`.

```py
diccionario = {
    "Peliculas": [
        {
            "Titulo": "A",
            "Generos": ["Drama", "Belico"]
        },
        {
            "Titulo": "B",
            "Generos": ["Accion", "Belico"],
        }
    ]
}

generos = input("Elige 2 géneros ").split() #generamos una lista con los generos
# print(generos)

for peli in diccionario["Peliculas"]:
    if not any([peli["Generos"][i] in generos for i in range(len(peli["Generos"]))]):
        diccionario["Peliculas"].remove(peli)

print(diccionario)
```

Teniendo como resultado

```
{'Peliculas': [{'Titulo': 'B', 'Generos': ['Accion', 'Belico']}]}
```

Si tal vez no te quedó claro el funcionamiento de `any()`, puedes leer la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=any#any)